# Iterate over Float list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, enumerate

I am trying to iterate over a list of float values using for loop but getting the error. I am trying to print the list using enumerate(). Is there a better way to iterate over a list of floats?

The list has numbers like `list_float= [1546626931.138813,1546626931.138954,1546626931.139053,1546626931.139289,.......,1546628078.463885]`

Code is:

```
import csv
import datetime
import pandas


filename = open('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\BLF File\\output.csv', "w")
log = can.BLFReader('C:\\Users\\xyz\\Downloads\\BLF File\\test.blf')

# print ("We are here!")
log_output = []
timestamp = [] #Variable to store timestamps from blf file
time_del = [] #Variable to store time difference
# filename.write('Timestamp              ID             DLC                 Channel' + '\n')

print('We are here 1')
for time in log:
    time = str(time).split()
    timestamp = float(time[1])
    # print(timestamp)


for count, item in enumerate(timestamp):
    print(count, item)
```

It is only printing the last float value in the list which is '**1546628078.463885**' as below:

```
0 1
1 5
2 4
3 6
4 6
5 2
6 8
7 0
8 7
9 8
10 .
11 4
12 6
13 3
14 8
15 8
16 5
```

In the file I have passed the values are like below:

```
['Timestamp:', '1546626926.380693', 'ID:', '0366', 'S', 'DLC:', '8', '25', '80', 'f8', '7f', '00', '00', '00', '00', 'Channel:', '0']
['Timestamp:', '1546626926.381285', 'ID:', '0120', 'S', 'DLC:', '2', '00', '05', 'Channel:', '1']
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of what's in your `log` variable?

Comment: Your `timestamp` does not seem like a list of floats; it seems like a single float (`timestamp = float(time[1])`). Doesn't your code in the current state throw an error?

Comment: @Nakor I have edited my original question. please take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop overwrites `timestamp` each time, so in the end `timestamp` is a single float rather than a list of floats.

```
for time in log:
    time = str(time).split()
    timestamp = float(time[1])
```

You probably want:

```
for time in log:
    time = str(time).split()
    timestamp.append(float(time[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting my silly mistake. I have edited my original question can you take a look at it please. Thank you.

Comment: If you have something else to ask, please ask a new question. Then you can paste a link to your question here if you want. Don't just edit the question because that will confuse anyone else who might see this question later.

Comment: Ok I will post a new question.